# How to make function work after append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For example i'm using append, and for example i'm appendig button in to a div, and i have function $('button_id').click(... etc to work affter i append the div, how can i do that.I mean i get no errors, but the function is not starting, it's because i append and then i want to use the function but how to do that, i tryed with delegate, but same thing.I tryed with function in the button tag , onmouseover and then the function thing, but nothing it gives me function not found.What is the solution ?

I have two events, one event is click event that appends button, the other event is click event that does something if the button that was appended is clicked, but that second event is not working ?

Comment: You cannot have duplicate IDs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using :

```
$(elem).live(...)
```

It will bind event for now and in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it always helps if you show us the exact source code. `$('button_id')` is the incorrect selector to start with, try something more along the lines of `$('#button_id')` as your selector. Also, are you appending dynamic content? Anyways, I've always used the `delegate()` function quite successfully, but have you tried using the `live()` function? Also, one more thing to make sure of is that you have the newest version of jQuery as your source.

As was stated as well, you can not have duplicate ids, if you want to have a pointer, use class, instead of `id="some_id"` use `class="appended"`. To select those using jQuery, use the selector like this `$('.appended')`.

Comment: Please see the edited part, yes i know that it must be with #

Comment: Source. The reason we ask for source is not only so we can see exactly what you are trying to do, but to see if there might be a syntactical error or even a simple spelling error that you might have overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this it will work as per your expectations.

```
$("#button_id").click(function(){

  //On click code goes here

}).appendTo($("#div_id"));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to determine the problem you're having without seeing your code, but `delegate` (or `live`) should be perfect for what you're trying to do:

```
$("body").delegate("#b", "click", function() { 
    alert("ok"); 
});

$("#example").append('<input type="button" id="b" value="Click" />');
```

The click handler above will fire when an element with `id="b"` is clicked, whether or not that element happens to be in the DOM right now or not.

However, as others have noted, it's important to remember that IDs need to be unique within a document, so by the sounds of it you may be better of using classes instead.

You can see an example of the above code running [here](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/GFGSJ/).